# react native onpressin and onpressout

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I tried to create a long press button to keep counting, however the interval wont stop when I release the onPressOut

```
const App = () => {
      const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
      let timer;
      const onButtonPressIn = () => {
        timer = setInterval(() => {
          console.log("in");
          setCount(count => count + 1);
        }, 1000);
      } 

      const onButtonPressOut = () =>{
        console.log("out");
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
      return(
          <View>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.longbtn}
              activeOpacity={0.9}
              onPressIn={()=> onButtonPressIn()}
              onPressOut={()=> onButtonPressOut()}
              >
                <Text style={styles.longbtntt}>LONG PRESS TO START - {count}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
      )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method used to handle the timer is not the exact one for the sort of use case you are trying to implement it for. You have to use `clearTimeout` instead of `clearInterval` when you're dismissing the `Timer` . Solution is as below, just modify it to use hooks.

```
 import React from 'react';
 import {
   SafeAreaView,
   View,
   Dimensions,
   TouchableOpacity,
   Text
 } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     counter: 0
   };
   this.timer = null;
 }

 addOne = () => {
   this.setState({counter: this.state.counter+1});
   this.timer = setTimeout(this.addOne, 200);
 }

 stopTimer = () => {
  clearTimeout(this.timer);
 }

render() {
  const screenHeight = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').height);
  return (
  <SafeAreaView>
  <View style={{height: screenHeight}}>
     <TouchableOpacity 
       style={{backgroundColor: "#FFC0CB"}}
       onPressIn={this.addOne} 
       onPressOut={this.stopTimer}
     >
      <Text>Press to start</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
     <Text>{this.state.counter}</Text>
     </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: can you do in react function component way ?

Answer (score 0):

The timer changes value when you assign a new interval to it, but the function `onButtonPressOut` remembers the value that `timer` had when the function was created. You can use `useCallback` here, like so:

```
const onButtonPressOut = useCallback(() => { //same thing }, [timer]);
```

This will update the function whenever `timer` changes and clear the appropriate interval.